# Flutter set date of InputDatePickerFormField programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart

The `InputDatePickerFormField` is a widget that presents a `TextFormField` and allows the user to enter a date manually as a string. This is fine and works great on its own (although I can't find a way to set its date format to `dd/mm/yyyy` instead of the default `mm/dd/yyyy`).

I want to also give the user the option to choose a date from the `datePicker` UI, but that means capturing the selected date from the picker and then programmatically setting this date to the form field. The `InputDatePickerFormField` class does not expose its `controller` for setting the string on the field, and there are no public methods for doing so.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My "system locale" is "en_US" and can't seem to change it ...

Answer (score 0):

In the Flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDatePickerFormField-class.html) is written

> When the field is saved or submitted, the text will be parsed into a DateTime according to the ambient locale's compact date format.

It means it is formatted automatically after the date change. The "the ambient locale's compact date format" is automatically determined from user device settings. You can set supported localization at the app level as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). You can play with user device localization in Chrome to verify it is working properly (the first language is used for app localization). [image: Set default device localization in Chrome].